# How to enable live color code change

Tags: jquery

When user types  in the color key can is it posisble to reflect it under the box 
need some what of live experience

I have tried as this show below , but it works when user leaves that field

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#color-2').change(function () {
    var eneteredcolor =  $('#color-2').val();
    if(eneteredcolor.length>=7)
    {
     $('.advanced').css('background-color', eneteredcolor);    
   }
});

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/17249/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have edited your code , it shows the new color code in the text box if the color is changed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#color-2').keyup(function() {
      var eneteredcolor = $('#color-2').val();
      if (eneteredcolor.length >= 4) {
        $('.advanced').css('background-color', eneteredcolor);
      }
    });
  
var z=setInterval(function(){
    var x = $(".advanced").css('backgroundColor');
    hexc(x);
    $("#color-2").val(color);
}, 50);

$('#color-2').click(function(){
clearInterval(z);
});
    $('#color-2').keyup(function() {
      var eneteredcolor = $('#color-2').val();
      if (eneteredcolor.length >= 4) {
        $('.advanced').css('background-color', eneteredcolor);
      }
    });

});


(function($, window, document) {
  "use strict";

  var pluginName = "colorpicker",
    defaults = {
      bind: "click keyup",
      position: "below"
    };


  /* GLOBALS
  ==================== */
  var win = $(window),
    doc = $(document);

  // RegExp
  var hexregex = /^(?:[0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}$/i,
    rgbregex = /rgba?\([^)]/g,
    hlsaregex = /hsla?\([^)]/g,
    colornameRegex = /^[a-z]+$/;


  /* COLOR NAMES
  ==================== */
  var colorNames = {
    aliceblue: "f0f8ff",
    antiquewhite: "faebd7",
    aqua: "00ffff",
    aquamarine: "7fffd4",
    azure: "f0ffff",
    beige: "f5f5dc",
    bisque: "ffe4c4",
    black: "000000",
    blanchedalmond: "ffebcd",
    blue: "0000ff",
    blueviolet: "8a2be2",
    brown: "a52a2a",
    burlywood: "deb887",
    cadetblue: "5f9ea0",
    chartreuse: "7fff00",
    chocolate: "d2691e",
    coral: "ff7f50",
    cornflowerblue: "6495ed",
    cornsilk: "fff8dc",
    crimson: "dc143c",
    cyan: "00ffff",
    darkblue: "00008b",
    darkcyan: "008b8b",
    darkgoldenrod: "b8860b",
    darkgray: "a9a9a9",
    darkgreen: "006400",
    darkkhaki: "bdb76b",
    darkmagenta: "8b008b",
    darkolivegreen: "556b2f",
    darkorange: "ff8c00",
    darkorchid: "9932cc",
    darkred: "8b0000",
    darksalmon: "e9967a",
    darkseagreen: "8fbc8f",
    darkslateblue: "483d8b",
    darkslategray: "2f4f4f",
    darkturquoise: "00ced1",
    darkviolet: "9400d3",
    deeppink: "ff1493",
    deepskyblue: "00bfff",
    dimgray: "696969",
    dodgerblue: "1e90ff",
    feldspar: "d19275",
    firebrick: "b22222",
    floralwhite: "fffaf0",
    forestgreen: "228b22",
    fuchsia: "ff00ff",
    gainsboro: "dcdcdc",
    ghostwhite: "f8f8ff",
    gold: "ffd700",
    goldenrod: "daa520",
    gray: "808080",
    green: "008000",
    greenyellow: "adff2f",
    honeydew: "f0fff0",
    hotpink: "ff69b4",
    indianred: "cd5c5c",
    indigo: "4b0082",
    ivory: "fffff0",
    khaki: "f0e68c",
    lavender: "e6e6fa",
    lavenderblush: "fff0f5",
    lawngreen: "7cfc00",
    lemonchiffon: "fffacd",
    lightblue: "add8e6",
    lightcoral: "f08080",
    lightcyan: "e0ffff",
    lightgoldenrodyellow: "fafad2",
    lightgrey: "d3d3d3",
    lightgreen: "90ee90",
    lightpink: "ffb6c1",
    lightsalmon: "ffa07a",
    lightseagreen: "20b2aa",
    lightskyblue: "87cefa",
    lightslateblue: "8470ff",
    lightslategray: "778899",
    lightsteelblue: "b0c4de",
    lightyellow: "ffffe0",
    lime: "00ff00",
    limegreen: "32cd32",
    linen: "faf0e6",
    magenta: "ff00ff",
    maroon: "800000",
    mediumaquamarine: "66cdaa",
    mediumblue: "0000cd",
    mediumorchid: "ba55d3",
    mediumpurple: "9370d8",
    mediumseagreen: "3cb371",
    mediumslateblue: "7b68ee",
    mediumspringgreen: "00fa9a",
    mediumturquoise: "48d1cc",
    mediumvioletred: "c71585",
    midnightblue: "191970",
    mintcream: "f5fffa",
    mistyrose: "ffe4e1",
    moccasin: "ffe4b5",
    navajowhite: "ffdead",
    navy: "000080",
    oldlace: "fdf5e6",
    olive: "808000",
    olivedrab: "6b8e23",
    orange: "ffa500",
    orangered: "ff4500",
    orchid: "da70d6",
    palegoldenrod: "eee8aa",
    palegreen: "98fb98",
    paleturquoise: "afeeee",
    palevioletred: "d87093",
    papayawhip: "ffefd5",
    peachpuff: "ffdab9",
    peru: "cd853f",
    pink: "ffc0cb",
    plum: "dda0dd",
    powderblue: "b0e0e6",
    purple: "800080",
    red: "ff0000",
    rosybrown: "bc8f8f",
    royalblue: "4169e1",
    saddlebrown: "8b4513",
    salmon: "fa8072",
    sandybrown: "f4a460",
    seagreen: "2e8b57",
    seashell: "fff5ee",
    sienna: "a0522d",
    silver: "c0c0c0",
    skyblue: "87ceeb",
    slateblue: "6a5acd",
    slategray: "708090",
    snow: "fffafa",
    springgreen: "00ff7f",
    steelblue: "4682b4",
    tan: "d2b48c",
    teal: "008080",
    thistle: "d8bfd8",
    tomato: "ff6347",
    turquoise: "40e0d0",
    violet: "ee82ee",
    violetred: "d02090",
    wheat: "f5deb3",
    white: "ffffff",
    whitesmoke: "f5f5f5",
    yellow: "ffff00",
    yellowgreen: "9acd32"
  };


  var cpk = {};
  cpk.saturation = {};
  cpk.hue = {};
  cpk._hsv = {
    h: 0,
    s: 0,
    v: 0
  };

  // only a single colorpicker should be active at any time
  cpk.singleton = function() {
    $.data(this, cpk._parent.val());
    var _cpk = $("#cpk-colorpicker").show();

    if (!_cpk.length) _cpk = $('<div id="cpk-colorpicker"><div id="cpk-sat-picker"><div id="cpk-sat-cursor" class="cpk-cursor" style="left:-4px;top:-4px;"></div></div><div id="cpk-hue-picker"><div id="cpk-hue-cursor" class="cpk-cursor" style="top:-3px;"></div></div></div>').appendTo("body");

    // set up some helpers
    cpk.saturation.picker = _cpk.find("#cpk-sat-picker");
    cpk.saturation.cursor = _cpk.find("#cpk-sat-cursor");
    cpk.hue.picker = _cpk.find("#cpk-hue-picker");
    cpk.hue.cursor = _cpk.find("#cpk-hue-cursor");

    cpk.saturation.picker.mousedown(function(e) {
      cpk.saturation.update(e);
      doc.mousemove(cpk.saturation.update);
    });

    cpk.hue.picker.mousedown(function(e) {
      cpk.hue.update(e);
      doc.mousemove(cpk.hue.update);
    });

    doc.mouseup(function() {
      doc.off("mousemove");
    });

    doc.click(function() {
      cpk.close();
    });

    _cpk.click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

    return _cpk;
  };

  cpk.register = function() {

    // position + offset
    cpk.reposition();

    var color = cpk._parent.val();
    if (!color.replace(/ |#/g, '').match(hexregex) && !colorNames[color]) color = (typeof cpk.settings.color === "function") ? cpk.settings.color(cpk._parent) : cpk.settings.color;
    cpk.set(color ? (colorNames[color] || color) : $.data(this, "defaultColor") || "#ffffff");
  };

  cpk.reposition = function() {
    var position = cpk._parent.offset();
    var offsetX = cpk.settings.position === "right" ? cpk._parent.outerWidth() + 5 : 0;
    var offsetY = cpk.settings.position === "below" ? cpk._parent.outerHeight() + 5 : 0;

    cpk.singleton().css({
      left: position.left + offsetX,
      top: position.top + offsetY
    });
  };

  // force the colorpicker to close
  cpk.close = function() {
    $("#cpk-colorpicker").hide();
  };

  // colorpicker callback
  cpk.callback = function() {
    var hex = cpk.calc.hsvToHex(cpk._hsv),
      rgb = cpk.calc.hsvToRgb(cpk._hsv);

    if (cpk._parent.is("input")) cpk._parent.val(hex);
    if (cpk.settings.callback) cpk.settings.callback(hex, rgb, cpk._hsv, cpk._parent);
  };

  // repositions cursor and sets color values
  cpk.saturation.update = function(e) {
    var position = cpk.saturation.picker.offset();

    var x = e.pageX - Math.ceil(position.left);
    var y = e.pageY - Math.ceil(position.top);

    x = x < 0 ? 0 : x;
    x = x > 166 ? 166 : x;
    y = y < 0 ? 0 : y;
    y = y > 166 ? 166 : y;

    cpk.saturation.cursor.css({
      left: x - 4,
      top: y - 4
    });

    cpk._hsv.s = Math.round(x / 166 * 100);
    cpk._hsv.v = Math.round(100 - (y / 166 * 100));

    cpk.callback();
  };

  // repositions cursor and sets color values
  cpk.hue.update = function(e) {
    var position = cpk.hue.picker.offset();
    var y = e.pageY - Math.ceil(position.top);

    y = y < 0 ? 0 : y;
    y = y > 166 ? 166 : y;

    var offset = y ? 4 : 3;

    cpk.hue.cursor.css({
      top: y - offset
    });

    cpk._hsv.h = 360 - Math.round(y / 166 * 360);

    // update color map
    var bg = cpk.calc.hsvToHex({
      s: 100,
      v: 100,
      h: cpk._hsv.h
    });

    cpk.saturation.picker.css({
      backgroundColor: bg
    });

    cpk.callback();
  };

  // reposition cursors based on hex value
  cpk.set = function(hex) {
    // get the hsv color from hex
    if (hex) cpk._hsv = cpk.calc.hexToHsv(hex);

    var bg = cpk.calc.hsvToHex({
      s: 100,
      v: 100,
      h: cpk._hsv.h
    });
    cpk.saturation.picker.css({
      backgroundColor: bg
    });

    var x = cpk._hsv.s / 100 * 166;
    var y = (100 - cpk._hsv.v) / 100 * 166;

    cpk.saturation.cursor[0].style.left = (x - 4) + "px";
    cpk.saturation.cursor[0].style.top = (y - 4) + "px";

    var hy = 166 - (cpk._hsv.h / 360 * 166);
    var offset = (hy) ? 4 : 3;

    cpk.hue.cursor.css({
      // top: (hy - offset) + "px"
    });
  };


  cpk.calc = {

    // convert hsv value to rgb
    // http://mjijackson.com/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript
    hsvToRgb: function(hsv) {

      var r, g, b;
      var h = hsv.h / 360,
        s = hsv.s / 100,
        v = hsv.v / 100;

      var i = Math.floor(h * 6);
      var f = h * 6 - i;
      var p = v * (1 - s);
      var q = v * (1 - f * s);
      var t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s);

      switch (i % 6) {
        case 0:
          r = v;
          g = t;
          b = p;
          break;
        case 1:
          r = q;
          g = v;
          b = p;
          break;
        case 2:
          r = p;
          g = v;
          b = t;
          break;
        case 3:
          r = p;
          g = q;
          b = v;
          break;
        case 4:
          r = t;
          g = p;
          b = v;
          break;
        case 5:
          r = v;
          g = p;
          b = q;
          break;
      }

      return {
        r: r * 255,
        g: g * 255,
        b: b * 255
      };
    },


    // convert rgb value to hsv
    // http://mjijackson.com/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript
    rgbToHsv: function(rgb) {

      var r = rgb.r / 255,
        g = rgb.g / 255,
        b = rgb.b / 255;

      var max = Math.max(r, g, b),
        min = Math.min(r, g, b);

      var h, s, v = max;

      var d = max - min;
      s = max === 0 ? 0 : d / max;

      if (max == min) {
        h = 0; // achromatic
      } else {
        switch (max) {
          case r:
            h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0);
            break;
          case g:
            h = (b - r) / d + 2;
            break;
          case b:
            h = (r - g) / d + 4;
            break;
        }

        h /= 6;
      }

      return {
        h: h * 360,
        s: s * 100,
        v: v * 100
      };
    },


    // convert rgb to hex
    rgbToHex: function(rgb) {
      return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (rgb.r << 16) + (rgb.g << 8) + rgb.b).toString(16).slice(1, 7).toUpperCase();
    },


    // convert hex value to rgb
    hexToRgb: function(hex) {
      hex = hex.replace(/ |#/g, '');
      if (hex.length === 3) hex = hex.replace(/./g, function(e, i) {
        var arr = [];
        return arr[i % 1] = Array(3).join(e);
      });
      hex = hex.match(/../g);
      return {
        r: parseInt(hex[0], 16),
        g: parseInt(hex[1], 16),
        b: parseInt(hex[2], 16)
      };
    },

    // convert hex value to hsv
    hexToHsv: function(hex) {
      return cpk.calc.rgbToHsv(cpk.calc.hexToRgb(hex));
    },


    // convert hsv value to hex
    hsvToHex: function(hsv) {
      var c = cpk.calc.hsvToRgb(hsv);
      return cpk.calc.rgbToHex(c);
    }
  };


  $.fn.colorpicker = function(settings) {
    settings = $.extend({}, defaults, settings);

    return this.bind(settings.bind, function(e) {
      cpk._parent = $(this);
      cpk.settings = settings;
      cpk.register();
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  };

}(jQuery, window, document));


$(function() {
  $("input.basic").colorpicker();

  $("a.advanced").colorpicker({
    callback: function(hex, rgb, hsv, el) {
      el.css({
        backgroundColor: hex
      });
      $("#" + el.attr("data-id")).val(hex);
      $('.rgb').val(rgb.g, rgb.g, rgb.b);
      $(".hsv").val(hsv);
    },
    color: function(el) {
      return $("#" + el.attr("data-id")).val();
    },
    position: "right"
  });
});
$('#picker').colorpicker()
function hexc(colorval) {
    var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    delete(parts[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
        if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
    }
    color = '#' + parts.join('');
}
```

```css
#cpk-colorpicker {
  background-color: #444;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

#cpk-sat-picker {
  background: #ff0000 url(https://github.com/triff/colorpicker/raw/master/images/saturation.png) no-repeat;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='https://github.com/triff/colorpicker/raw/master/images/saturation.png', sizingMethod='scale');
  border: 1px solid #222;
  cursor: crosshair;
  float: left;
  height: 166px;
  position: relative;
  width: 166px;
}

#cpk-sat-picker .cpk-cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  background: url(https://github.com/triff/colorpicker/raw/master/images/sat-cursor.gif) no-repeat;
}

#cpk-hue-picker {
  background: url(https://github.com/triff/colorpicker/raw/master/images/hue.png) no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  height: 166px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  position: relative;
  width: 19px;
}

#cpk-hue-picker .cpk-cursor {
  background: url(https://github.com/triff/colorpicker/raw/master/images/hue-cursor.gif) no-repeat;
  height: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -4px;
  width: 27px;
}

section {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

label {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.advanced-input {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.advanced {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 19px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> <span class="advanced-input"><label for="color-2">Color:</label><input id="color-2" type="text" value="#00ff00" /></span>
  <a class="advanced" href="#" style="background-color:#00ff00;"></a>
</p>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290231/is-it-wrong-to-ask-for-an-explanation-of-how-why-the-code-works-in-code-only-ans

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#color-2').keyup(function() {
  var eneteredcolor = $('#color-2').val();
  if (eneteredcolor.length >= 4) { //replace 7 with 4 since colors also have shorthand codes eg #000 for black
    $('.advanced').css('background-color', eneteredcolor);
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/o2gxgz9r/17252/

**Note**: replace 7 with 4 since colors also have shorthand codes eg #000 for black

Comment: Good point about 7 vs 4, might be better to remove the check completely, then you can also use words, eg "blue" https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/17256/ (might be open to abuse though, not checked).

Comment: @freedomn-m Definitely.

Answer (score 1):

The `.change` event only fires when the control leaves focus (depending on the control and the browser).

You can use `.keyup` to trigger as keys are pressed (https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/17251/), but this doesn't work with paste, so use `.on("input",`

```
$('#color-2').on("input", function () {
  var enteredcolor =  $('#color-2').val();
  if (enteredcolor.length>=7)
  {
    $('.advanced').css('background-color', enteredcolor);    
  }
```

Updated fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/17253/

Answer (score 0):

Change event is evaluated when the user leaves the box afaik.

From jquery:

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to  elements,  boxes and 
>   elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event
>   is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse,
>   but for the other element types the event is deferred until the
>   element loses focus.

Edit: keyup event might be a solution for your problem

Comment: Hi, this is a useful description of the problem, but does not provide an answer.